# NSMutableArray Labels iphoneapp

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

Because I'm a newbie I'm confused about why this is not possible. I have created an array: `NSMutableArray *labels` and added a few `UILabel` objects to it. I did this because I wanted to easily change the textcolour of all of the labels without having to do it individually, but when I call

```
_labels.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:137.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

It gives me an error that textColor can't be used with a MutableArray. Is there another way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You want to change color of all lables in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current try you would change the textcolor of the array (if there where one). You have to call the method on every `UILabel` in the array.
to do something on all items in an array you can use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`

```
[_labels enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILabel *label, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    label.textColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:137.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]; 
}];
```

for more information about array look at the apple documentation about `NSMutableArray`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the items in the array and call the method on each label:

```
for (UILabel *label in _labels) {
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:137.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];    
}
```

The array won't do the messaging for you unless you ask it to:

```
[_labels makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setTextColor:) withObject:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```